# O que fazer com usuários que estão na zona de conforto?

Tags: debate

Existe um tipo de usuário que ao realizar uma pergunta parece não estar interessado no conhecimento envolvido para solucionar o seu problema, ele simplesmente quer a resposta definitiva, ou seja, só quer o código pronto.

Não está preocupado em aprender a linguagem ou o conceito, e sim em copiar o código respondido e colar em seu código. O que fazer nesses casos?

Pois acredito que o propósito do stackoverflow é incentivar o aprendizado e não só dar a resposta para ser colada no código fonte. Muitas vezes parece que a pessoa não chegou nem a pesquisar em outras comunidades ou até mesmo no google. Já vi casos assim no SO.com e estou vendo esses casos surgirem no SO.pt também.

Comment: Tipo o [Programa do Labirinto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11316/3117)? rsrs.. O engraçado é q eu abri a pergunta e vi no boletim da comunidade essa pergunta aqui do meta, bem do lado.

Comment: Eu ignoro todas as perguntas onde o autor poderia teclar 2 ou 3 palavras no google para encontrar mil e uma soluções numa fração de segundos. Aliás, são questões tão simples que até o Bing encontra. rsrs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Existem alguns casos que as pessoas criam uma publicação e apenas passam os requisitos a espera da solução, não chegam nem a literalmente fazer uma pergunta, é quase uma ordem:

> O sistema deve ter isso, isso e isso.

Não consegui achar nenhum exemplo assim pois geralmente essas publicações são apagadas, hoje mesmo teve um caso assim, talvez até por esse motivo você criou essa pergunta aqui, não é?

Nesses casos nem tente responder, adicione um comentário explicando para o autor que não é assim que o nosso site funciona, aqui é um site de perguntas e respostas e não um site de trabalho não remunerado. Peça antes de mais nada para o autor deixar claro **qual é a dúvida**, e lembre sempre que as perguntas devem ser o mais focadas possíveis, caso contrário a pergunta pode ser sinalizada como ampla demais.

Lembre também que qualquer usuário pode publicar quantas perguntas desejar, então não precisa ficar economizando publicações e perguntar tudo em uma só.

Tente sempre explicar isso com palavras cordiais e não chegar dando patadas, que nem estou acostumado a ver por aí. Estamos interessados em atrair pessoas, e não afastá-las.

Comment: Sinceramente sinto bastante disso na SO em inglês, as vezes eu faço uma pergunta, ok mal formulada e o pessoal, diz..pergunta ao Google, aprende a escrever primeiro, etc, etc...Claro que tenho minha culpa em formular incorretamente, porém as vezes basta um comentário para eu editar a pergunta e torna-la melhor!

Comment: Sente bastante disso oq? Patada?

Answer (score 8):

Felipe, apesar de concordar que idealmente todos deviam estar interessados em compreender como a resposta soluciona o problema, a verdade é que muitos querem só a solução.

Eu penso que a vida os ensinará que quanto mais compreenderem o problema e a solução mais facilmente saem de problemas na próxima vez.

De qualquer maneira não podemos obrigar utilizadores a aprenderem. O que podems fazer é explicar bem a resposta para eles lerem e serem guiados para o conhecimento através da boa descrição na resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Bom acho que existem 2 possibilidades:

- O Cara faz a pergunta e quer apenas a resposta, ok o SO é para isso correto? Nem todos precisam saber o porque de tudo, apenas como fazer já é o suficiente.
- Porém em casos como o Math disse: Eu quero isso, assim e com aquilo, ai já é outra coisa, o cara quer tercerizar o serviço dele? Ai deveria ou ser apagada a resposta...ou suspensa, etc.